# How to subtract the last number/element in a separate list of tuples having multiple criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, subtraction

```
samplelist1 = [('A', 'Pass', 20), ('A', 'Failed', 5), ('B', 'Pass', 10), ('B', 'Failed', 5) ]

samplelist2 = [('A', 'Pass', 2), ('A', 'Failed', 1), ('B', 'Failed', 2)]

# Expected Output: result = [('A', 'Pass', 18), ('A', 'Failed', 4), ('B', 'Pass', 10), ('B', 'Failed', 3)
```

Can I Still use this code ??? 
Using this code as my reference

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for letter, status, value in samplelist:
    d[(letter, status)] += value
res = [key + (val,) for key, val in d.items()] # convert to required format
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code won't work, because it uses `samplelist`, but your data only contains `samplelist1` and `samplelist2`. I'm assuming this was a error and you forgot to include the loop where you iterate the sample lists.

In any case, I don't think you need a `defaultdict`. Just traverse `samplelist1`, set the values in a dictionary, then traverse `samplelist2`, and deduct the values from the dictionary.

```
samplelist1 = [('A', 'Pass', 20), ('A', 'Failed', 5), ('B', 'Pass', 10), ('B', 'Failed', 5) ]

samplelist2 = [('A', 'Pass', 2), ('A', 'Failed', 1), ('B', 'Failed', 2)]

d = {}
for x, y, z in samplelist1:
    d[x, y] = z

for x, y, z in samplelist2:
    d[x, y] -= z

result = [(k1, k2, v) for (k1, k2), v in d.items()]

print(result)
```

If we really want to use a `defaultdict`, we could modify your approach to first collect the items in a list, then minus the first item from the second item(if more than one element exists):

```
from collections import defaultdict

samplelist1 = [('A', 'Pass', 20), ('A', 'Failed', 5), ('B', 'Pass', 10), ('B', 'Failed', 5) ]

samplelist2 = [('A', 'Pass', 2), ('A', 'Failed', 1), ('B', 'Failed', 2)]

d = defaultdict(list)
for samplelist in (samplelist1, samplelist2):
    for x, y, z in samplelist:
        d[x, y].append(z)

result = [(k1, k2, v[0] - v[1] if len(v) > 1 else v[0]) for (k1, k2), v in d.items()]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[('A', 'Pass', 18), ('A', 'Failed', 4), ('B', 'Pass', 10), ('B', 'Failed', 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you RoadRunner for the quick response.!! :)
I tried the first code without the 'defaultdic', it worked. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use use basic for loop with a if condition :

```
>>> result = [tuple(l1[:2]) + tuple([l1[-1] - l2[-1]]) for l1 in samplelist1 for l2 in samplelist2 if l1[:2]==l2[:2]]
```

or using pandas :

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(samplelist1, columns=['letter', 'status', 'value'])
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(samplelist2, columns=['letter', 'status', 'value'])
>>> df = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['letter', 'status'], right_on=['letter', 
'status']).dropna()
>>> df['value'] = df['value_x'] - df['value_y']
>>> df.head()
  letter  status  value_x  value_y  value
0      A    Pass       20        2     18
1      A  Failed        5        1      4
2      B  Failed        5        2      3
```

Comment: Thank you for helping Oussa.!! :)